# gradle set a global property for all projects from gradle

Tags: gradle

I would like to set a property from within gradle (for example from settings.gradle) in a way similar to `gradle.properties` or `-D`. Is it possible?

The following code demonstrates what I am trying to do but its not working:

```gradle
import org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem
def getArchitecture() {
    return System.getProperty("os.arch")
}

def getName() {
    if(OperatingSystem.current().isMacOsX()) {
        return "darwin"
    } else if(OperatingSystem.current().isLinux()) {
        return "linux"
    } else {
        throw Exception("The operating system you use is not supported.")
    }
}

allprojects {
    ext {
        // this variable has to be visible from all the projects 
        // and .gradle files in the same way as if it was set 
        // from gradle.properties file
        buildMachine = getName() + "_" + getArchitecture()
    }
}
```

## Edit

I would like this property to be defined in settings.gradle and be visible in all other .gradle file

## Edit2

I have a number of build machines and I don't want to specify the value of the variable `buildMachine` (in settings and in other `.gradle` files) and I wouldn't like it to be passed with `-P` or with `gradle.properties`, because it seems its possible to figure out this property purely within gradle

Comment: Why do you want it available in settings.gradle?

Comment: I am setting things up in settings.gradle and some directory names depend on this variable. I think its not unnatural to want something like that

Comment: I've removed my answer. Your question isn't clear enough, and my attempts aren't helping focus in on it.

Comment: @MarkFisher please see my second edit

Answer (score 1):

You could simply set this property for the rootProject and in all other gradle scripts or subprojects, read from it..

For clarity sake..

in your root build.gradle

`ext {
   buildMachine = getName() + "_" + getArchitecture()
}`

and in your subprojects..

`ext {
   println rootProject.buildMachine
}`

Comment: any idea why `allProjects { ext.asdf = "exist" }; project('A'){ version = ext.asdf }` fails with "no such extra property asdf"?